# Rstudio git repo csv file to data frame not importing proper data

Tags: r, csv, github

For school project.
In RStudio version 2022.02.1+461, I'm trying to download a csv file from GitHub, then import to data frame.
Here's what's in the chunk:

```
url <- "https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv"
DF_csv <- read.csv(confirmed_url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(DF_csv)

                                                                  X..DOCTYPE.html.
1 <html lang=en data-color-mode=auto data-light-theme=light data-dark-theme=dark >
2                                                                           <head>
3                                                             <meta charset=utf-8>
4                     <link rel=dns-prefetch href=https://github.githubassets.com>
5               <link rel=dns-prefetch href=https://avatars.githubusercontent.com>
6               <link rel=dns-prefetch href=https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com>
```

No error messages during rendering. I've also checked the tail. Not workable. The data frame has 431 obs. with 1 variable.
I've tried to check the package versions, IDE versions, I've tried curl with read.csv(), same thing. Apparently, it's a time series, so I was expecting some sort of numerical data for analysis.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Try this link: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv` instead.

Comment: Also try `read_csv('https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/raw/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv')`